# How to upgrade query caching from CI3 to CI4 and reuse a CodeIgniter4 Active Record

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

I'm trying to reuse query for counting total rows before and after I set limit in CI3, I use caching before.

How to do it in CI4 ?

here is my query

```
    $sql = $this->db->start_cache()
        ->select(<<some_items>>)
        ->from(<<items_table>>)
        ->where(<<condition>>)
        ->group_by(<<group_by_condition>>)
        ->order_by(<<order_by_condition>>)
        ->stop_cache();

    $total    = $sql->get()->num_rows();

    $sql= $this->db->limit(10, 10)->get();

    $data = $sql->result_array();
    $total_per_limit    = $sql->num_rows();

    $this->db->flush_cache();
```

Comment: You should add an answer with what you did to solve the problem so that others can benefit

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$total    = $sql->countAllResults(false);

$sql = $sql->get(10, 10);

$total_per_limit    = $sql->getNumRows();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).